# Static font size preview in combobox panel - ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

How can I set a static font size, e.g. 14px, in the font size combobox panel in ckeditor? By default it previews the actual size. Since the width of the panel is static, font sizes above 72 are not shown.

Wanted: Static font-size preview in combobox panel

[image]

Default: Dynamic font-size preview in combobox panel

[image]

Br
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the list item style in `content.css`. Add this style definition:

```
.cke_panel_listItem span {
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

Here's a screenshot after applying this change:

[image]